# error while magento installation

Tags: installation, magento2.4.1, magento-install

Deprecated Functionality: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php on line 159

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.4.1 required php 7.4. it will not work with PHP 8

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to downgrade your php version. Please see below command (Linux).

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2 && sudo a2dismod php7.3 && sudo a2dismod php8.0 && sudo a2enmod php7.4 && sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4

sudo service apache2 restart
```

now try again.

Answer (score 1):

For the installation of Magento 2.4.1 please follow this specified Requirement for your Development environment... [image: Magento Specified Requirement For 2.4.1]

Thank You!!!